# Cannot install armv7l ISO in qemu virt-manager on Ubuntu 20.04 running on x86-64

Tags: uefi, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, arm, qemu

I would like to install Debian in a virtual machine for the armv7l architecture and I can't select ISO boot because virt-manager failed to set up UEFI: did not find any UEFI binary path for arch 'armv7l', and install operations are limited. I proceeded to install the following packages: `qemu-efi`, `qemu-efi-arm`. Then I tried again, but it made no difference. How can I set up UEFI to work with qemu-system-arm?

Answer (score 0):

When using virt-manager to build a new armv7l VM using an existing EFI disk image the first screen will display "*Warning: Failed to setup UEFI: Did not find any UEFI binary path for arch 'armv7l'. Install options are limited.*"

[image: screenshot of virt-manager installing armv7l guest step 1 of 4]

Proceed ahead anyway, by the time you get to screen 4, check the "Customize image before install" checkbox.

[image: screenshot of virt-manager nstalling armv7l guest step 4 of 4]

On the overview there will be a drop-down menu that lets you pick the EFI firmware that the first screen said it could not find.

[image: screenshot of virt-manager installing armv7l guest customize before install overview]

Click [Begin installation] and you'll be in the EFI shell.

[image: screenshot of virt-manager guest in EFI shell]

Yes, it's an armv7l.

[image]

The libvirt/Qemu system running the guest is Ubuntu not Arch because Arch doesn't have that defect; on Arch you can just use armv7l without being told by virt-manager that it can't find the UEFI binary path to the firmware file so you don't need a work-around on Arch.  It's just the VM guest in the examples is running Arch on Ubuntu.

The answer is also on this Fedora page but without the screenshots:
[virt-manager - Using UEFI with QEMU - Fedora Project Wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Using_UEFI_with_QEMU#virt-manager)